# Why the width changes before and after the page reloads(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a div

```
<div class="top_region" id="region">
    <span class="logged_email">
    <?= $string; ?>
    </span>
    <div class="top_arrow" style="cursor: pointer;" id="top_arrow_reg">
    <?= img('css/img/top_arrow.png'); ?>
    </div>
    <ul class="top_submenu" style="cursor: default;" id="top_submenu_reg">
        <li>
        <a href="<?= base_url() ?>region/bishkek">bishkek</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="<?= base_url() ?>region/osh">osh</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

the purpose is that the UL tag need to have the same width as the div, but the problem is that when i reload the page, the UL have a little bit more width than the div, but when i click on the LI link, then it gets normal, the div width == ul width, but i don't understand why that happens???

i am using JQuery

```
$("#top_arrow").toggle(function(){

            $("#top_submenu").slideDown(500);


    }, function(){

        $("#top_submenu").slideUp(500);

    })

var width = $(".top_region").width();
$(".top_submenu").width(width);
```

can someone explain this moment??, and how to fix it??

css

```
div.top_region
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
div.top_region  ul.top_submenu
{
    /*width: 100px;*/
    /*left: -105px;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
span.logged_email
{
    background: #333335;
    color: #dbdcde;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
div.top_arrow
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1px;
    position: relative;
    behavior: url('border-radius.htc');
    width: 20px;
}
div.top_arrow img
{
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    behavior: url('border-radius.htc');
    margin-top: 1px;
}
ul.top_submenu
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #303030;
    font-size: 8pt;
    display: none;
    /*width: 180px;*/
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*left: -170px;*/
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
}
ul.top_submenu li
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #969696;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
ul.top_submenu li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.top_submenu li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: still vague. do you have css for this? i don't see in the HTML a `.top_region` or a `.top_submenu` also. can you post ALL of the related code?

Answer (score 0):

that's exactly why:

```
var width = $(".top_region").width();
$(".top_submenu").width(width);​
```

their widths are equal.
make it :

```
var width = $(".top_region").width();
$(".top_submenu").width(width-2);​
```

---

update:
you have some errors in your code. please see my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LwGJX/7/

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work because the value inside the span changes, and the width are changing to, but the problem is that when i make ctrl + r and the UL width are more than the parent div, but if i click on the link then its get normal

Comment: well there wasn't any span initially.. still if you run above code on page load - it should work as your span formed by php before it outputs to browser. otherwise provide more details?

Comment: The first time the page loads it show 134px, and the before the click on the link it show 125, and the length of the string inside the span is the same, i check it with alert(width);

Comment: you code a bit messy.. i don't think your toggle works as you calling id but it should be class?... see my update

Comment: finally i found the solution, need to put the ul.top_submenu{ width: 100%}, and delete the Javascript width equalazing :)